# How to integrate Shopify in the flutter project with Null Safety Please?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, shopify

flutter Shopify: ^0.0.1 package Giving me exception of :(OS Error: No address associated with hostname, Errno = 7) #1

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shopify/shopify.dart';

void main() {
  Shopify.create(
    shop: 'shop-name',
    storeFrontApiToken: 'your-api-key',
  );

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Shopify Example',
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.redAccent),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Future<void> getData() async {
    final shopify = Shopify.instance;
    final data = await shopify.runQuery([
      ShopifyQuery.products()
        ..withFields(
          availableForSale: true,
          compareAtPriceRange: ShopifyProductPriceRange()
            ..withFields(
              maxVariantPrice: ShopifyMoney()
                ..withFields(
                  amount: true,
                ),
            ),
          createdAt: true,
          description: true,
          descriptionHtml: true,
          handle: true,
          id: true,
          onlineStoreUrl: true,
          options: ShopifyProductOptions()
            ..by(first: 5)
            ..withFields(
              id: true,
              name: true,
              values: true,
            ),
          priceRange: ShopifyProductPriceRange()
            ..withFields(
              maxVariantPrice: ShopifyMoney()
                ..withFields(
                  amount: true,
                ),
            ),
          productType: true,
          publishedAt: true,
          requiresSellingPlan: true,
          seo: ShopifySeo()
            ..withFields(
              description: true,
              title: true,
            ),
          tags: true,
          title: true,
          totalInventory: true,
          updatedAt: true,
          variantBySelectedOptions: ShopifyProductVariant()
            ..withFields(
              weight: true,
            ),
          // selectedOptions: true,
          vendor: true,
        )
        ..by(first: 4)
      // ..as(Article.fromJson),
    ]);

    // print(data);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: getData,
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have allowed the Internet permission, wifi is on on lapy and phone

I am providing the shop name like: verden-app.myshopify.com, and the storeFrontApiToken(from the private app which I have created), I have allowed read_write permission for all the options as well, help, please?

I am just running the given example and want to print data from my store

https://github.com/nonvanilla-shop/shopify_flutter

[image]

Comment: So? What is the problem? We cannot help you if you don't describe the problem you are having. Does it not compile? Do you get errors? Any exceptions at runtime?

Comment: I am trying to run the above-linked code, and getting an error(Question updated above)

Comment: Which line is giving that error? What is the code you are running? We are not magicians, we cannot magically know what you did wrong on your screen. You need to *share* that information.

Comment: Sir, I have clearly mentioned what the problem is, Could you please open up the GitHub link, which is the repo of the flutter plugin: Shopify 1.0.0, I am running the code in the given  link and it gives me a compile-time error: (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, Errno = 7): I will edit the question once again

Answer (score 0):

Your full error message says that it could not find an address for the URL "https". That is not surprising, since that is not a full address. You need to provide the full address in a valid format.

Since you have not actually posted your code, I can only guess... maybe there was a whitespace after the https part of your url that snuck in while you copied and pasted it? Or maybe you used a semicolon instead of a colon? Or maybe backslashes instead of forward slashes?

Answer (score 0):

For those of you, who may encounter this error in the future. My code runs successfully by just adding the shop name, i,e verden-app only in the shop name